# how to get new page's source code in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

Let's say there is a page and there is a "next page" button in it.
`browser` is initialized using `webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)`.
I use `page_source` attribute to get the orginal page's source code and locate the button for next page. Then I send click to it, the browser will turn to next page in the same tab in Chrome.

```
browser.get(origin_page_url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(btn_xpath).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

After above codes then I call `page_source` again, but what I get is the same as the original page's source code.
How can I get the newly opened page's source code?

Comment: Hello, can you provide us with the website URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `explicitly wait` for the new page to load before getting the page source. This usually depends on the webpage you are working with. For instance, you may wait until a particular element becomes visible:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))

element.click();
```

After that call `page_source`

**Import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I have not tested this but, sure this will work for you.